# passing "ref" between child components without click event Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I have two sibling components one has a form and the submit button is in the next component. I wanna pass ValidateObserver (from vee-validate) as a ref to other child component. And I use global Eventhub to communicate between sibling components.

```
// Component A
    <template>
        <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }" ref="FullForm">
          <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(buildingForm)">
    </template>

methods:{             

        buildingForm(){
            this.eventHub.$emit('building-form', data)
         
        },
},
```

And I'm catching it on component B

```
 //Component B

    methods(){

             buildingValidation(){
             this.$refs.FullForm.validate().then(success => {
                 if (!success) {
                     return this.step.id == this.currentstep;
                 }

             });
            

        },
             }
    
    created(){

            this.eventHub.$on('building-form', data => {  

            //Here I'm calling the function buildingValidation()

            console.log(data);     
            
            
            })
                
    
        },
```

What Am I missing? Thanks

Comment: If you call `this.$refs` on Component B it will return the refs from Component B not from Component A.

Comment: @user28 So, how should I do that?

Comment: I think the simplest way is pass the ref of Component A as props to Component B then use `this.componentA.$refs.FullForm` or may be using `$parent` to reduce code. But why not emit event from Component B back to Component A with some data to execute in Component A.

Comment: Those components are siblings. Is that ok to pass props between siblings?

Comment: You can't you have to pass via parent.